# Definition of "SR-ORG" CRS

Tags: coordinate-system

I've seen notes that `SR-ORG:####` means that the SRS/CRS/projection definition is user defined.  Is there an official location saying that?  Some of these feel official.  What is the canonical location for them?  Is it the `List user-contributed references` at https://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/ or is there a specification someplace that defines the there is an `SR-ORG` space?

Comment: Some discussion here: https://mobile.twitter.com/kurtschwehr/status/1527356527161462800

Answer (score 1):

https://spatialreference.org/about/
“There are currently three distinct catalogs of spatial reference systems on this website -- EPSG, ESRI, and User-defined (called sr-org)”

SR-ORG is shorthand for SpatialReference.ORG